# Nginx rewrite regex to rewrite root and subdirectory

Tags: regex, nginx, regex-group, nginx-config

Currently i have

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name default;

    location /foo/ {
        rewrite ^/foo(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_redirect https://example.com https://$host/;
    }
```

This matches foo and essentially strips it. I need to maintain this functionality, and also include bar if it is after foo. i.e. if the url is `/foo/bar` I want both of those essentially stripped.  I'm not great at regex and am struggling with the proper way to do this.

I'm thinking something like `(foo)|(\/bar)`, but not sure how to match a trailing slash with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add `/bar` as an optional component to your regex pattern:

```
rewrite ^/foo(/bar)?(/.*)$ $2 break;
```

Note that the capture group reference has been changed into `$2`

Comment: Or made the first group a non-capture one: `rewrite ^/foo(?:/bar)?(/.*)$ $1 break;` (should be a little more effective).